# How to put column value on last day of each month?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table 1:

```
Day         Campaign    Placement               Site    Impressions
3/1/2014    Boy Dog         ROS_728x90              CNN         100
3/2/2014    Boy Dog         Leaderboard             ESPN    250
3/3/2014    Boy Dog         RM_Something_300x250        CNN         38
3/2/2014    Boy Dog         ROS_728x90              CNN         102
```

Table 1 is daily data. Table 2 is Monthly table.

Table 2:

```
Month   Year    Campaign    Placement        Site    Actual Cost
3           2014    Boy Dog         ROS_728x90       CNN            1000
3           2014    Boy Dog         Leaderboard      ESPN           850
3           2014    Boy Dog         RM_Something_300x250 CNN            421
```

From table 1 and Table 2, I want to make Final Table as shown below. Moreover, from the Table 2 I only want to include cost which is monthly base and want to set on last day of each month for all placement as you can see in final table below.

There are thousands of Placement and I want to do same thing for all place as I have mentioned in final table for one placement only. I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Final table:

```
Day Campaign    Placement   Impressions Cost
3/1/2014    Boy Dog ROS_728x90  100          0
3/2/2014    Boy Dog ROS_728x90  102          0
3/3/2014    Boy Dog ROS_728x90  102          0
3/4/2014    Boy Dog ROS_728x90  102          0
3/31/2014   Boy Dog ROS_728x90  500          0
3/31/2014   Boy Dog ROS_728x90  0            1000
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a select

```
select *, cost from 
table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on year(t1.Day) = t2.year
 and month(t1.Day) = t2.month
```

for select cost only for the last day(if i understand) use this select

```
select *,
     case
         when  DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, t1.day) + 1, 0)) = t1.day then cost
         else 0
     end
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on year(t1.Day) = t2.year
and month(t1.Day) = t2.month
```

Comment: @user3402335: thanks for your suggestion, but can you tell me what is DATA belong to which column? As you have mentioned that p1.data and p.data (data = ?).

Comment: I have modified the query. I couldn't answer, so I answer just now

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. From your suggestion i can create table out of it, but i want to put all cost value on last day of each month. how can i do that?

Comment: in the last day of month do you want the sum of cost in every day?

Comment: Not everyday because cost is based on monthly base. so i want sum of cost on Placement base.

Comment: i don't understand, the last day now compare cost(1000) and for each other day 0. What should be on the table? on the new table?
if you have another problem i suggest to open a new question.